# Having firestore on my own server requires an additional request to reach my data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

If i initialize Cloud Firestore on my own server, then isn't it a "two way trip" to reach my data?

What i mean is, first the client-side has to make a request to my server, then my server has to make a request to firebase. Why should i do this and not just have my own mongoDB on the server? Isn't it bad that i have to make an extra request for every user's request?

I am not able to see a reason for me to use firebase if that is the case

I do not consider querying firebase directly from the client side safe, and that is not what i want to do.

Comment: Are you stating you want to host your own Cloud Firestore server? I don't believe that's an option as Firebase products are Cloud hosted only. Querying from the client side is safe and data is encrypted while in transit. You should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a matter of your choice. [Firebase Firestore Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or [Google Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) (this is pracitaly the same product) is Cloud, scalable and serverless solution. This means that it scale automatically and you do not have to care about infrastructure underneath. If you are confident that you enough resources to maintain you private server and database when your application will be growing I think its better to use on-premise solution.

I hope it will help!